# Mysql query for getting monthwise n th highest spending customer

Tags: mysql, sql

I am using sakila.payment table.
Columns: payment_id, customer_id, staff_id, rental_id, amount, payment_date, update_date

I am using this query to get customers spending the highest amount for each month.
How can I get the Nth highest spending customer for each month?

```
select customer_id,`month`,max(total_amount) from
(SELECT customer_id,count(customer_id) as `count`,month(payment_date) as `month`,sum(amount) as total_amount 
FROM sakila.payment
group by month(payment_date),customer_id 
order by `month` asc, `total_amount` desc)t
group by `month`
```

Comment: are you using `mysql 8.0`?

Comment: Yes, it is 8.0.15

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the following, if you are using `MySQL 8.0` then it will work with `row_number()`

```
select 
    customer_id,
    month,
    total_amount
from
(
    select 
        customer_id,
        month,
        total_amount,
        row_number() over (partition by month order by total_amount desc) as rnk
    from
    (
        select 
            customer_id,
            count(customer_id) as `count`,
            month(payment_date) as `month`,
            sum(amount) as total_amount,
        from sakila.payment
        group by 
            month(payment_date),
            customer_id 
    ) cal
) mnt

where rnk = 1
```

Comment: what is row_number() over (partition_by month, customer_id) doing?

Comment: @Harhaaakr this is a good read to understand `row_number()` https://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-window-functions/mysql-row_number-function/